Newrelic EKS unable to push logs from PVC in other namespace
I've used the nri-bundle helm chart to build up Newrelic interaction with Kubernetes logs.
Pushing logs from input /var/log/containers/ logs to new relic is working properly.
Nevertheless, my application writes logs to the pvc log directory in the development namespace. I have included permanent volume information to the extra mount section of the values.yaml file in the Helm file.
I am unable to locate the pvc claim message on the pod description, but my deployment with pvc and the mount path indicated is complete with pending status.
My requirement is to push logs from /log directory in container mounted to pv to newrelic.
If I deploy Newlic in same namespace as application, its able to find and push logs to newrelic.
I have service account fluentbit-sa, its able to access pvc successfully.
kubectl get pvc <PVC_NAME> -n <PVC_NAMESPACE> --as=system:serviceaccount:<FLUENTBIT_NAMESPACE>:fluentbit-sa
Newrelic logging values.yaml below configuration is used to mount pvc to fluentbit
extraVolumeMounts:

name: logs-test
mountPath: /logs  # Path where the PVC will be mounted in the container
readOnly: true

extraVolumes:

name: logs-test
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: test
claimNamespace: test

Deployment in Pending status
